# Automate Receipt Filing from Emil

Tags: applescript

I currently have a workflow setup that when I get a paper receipt I highlight the company name and price in green then scan with my ScanSnap which it then OCR's.  Then using Hazel I automate the filing so that it saves anything in green as a keyword.  Then Hazel auto matches the date and renames and files the PDF based on the Company, Date and total.

So as odd as it is I'm not sure how to do this when I get an email receipt or a receipt from a we page.  The only way I can get it to work is to actually print out the receipt and do the same process.

Every time I do that it feels like I'm moving backwards in terms of automation.  Does anyone know a way I can highlight a PDF to save as keywords in Hazel?

Answer (score 1):

If you open the PDF in Preview, you can manually add keywords to the PDF. There is no need to highlight the words first.

Open the Inspector (Command - i) and the click the tab that looks like a magnifying glass.  Click the + button on the bottom left and you can add the keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Depending what you use to open the PDF files.

In Adobe reader there is a Highlight tool where you can choose the coleor and save it as default.

In Preview (which is the default pdf for Mail.app) there is also a Highlight tool and here you can also choose the highlight color.

In this example the top line was marked in adobe Reder XI, and the bottom line was marked in Preview application.

[image: pdf with markings]
Here are the [instructions how to make a highlighted text a keyword.](http://www.macdrifter.com/2013/12/redacted-and-encrypted-pdfs-with-hazel-and-pdfpenpro.html)

[image: marked text as keyword in pdf]

Comment: I have PDF pen which has the highlight tool. How do I make the highlights show up as keywords?